# I can't access wordpress functions from an ajax php call

Tags: plugins, ajax

I've seen a few questions similar to this but I can't find a solution to the issue I have.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_LogHit_callback', 'LogHit_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_LogHit_callback', 'LogHit_callback');
function HitCount() {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'LogHit_callback',
        PostId:'<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>'
    };

    jQuery.post('http://www.test.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data);
 });
 </script>
<?php

function LogHit_callback() {
  global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

  $postId = $_POST['PostId'];
  $hits = get_post_meta((int)$postId, 'hit-counter', true);
  $hits = $hits + 1;
  update_post_meta((int)$postId, 'hit-counter', (int)$hits);
  exit; // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

When I call the HitCount function in my page it renders the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var data = {
    action: 'LogHit_callback',
    PostId:'86476'
};
jQuery.post('http://www.test.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data);
  });
</script>
```

The direct link to the admin-ajax.php file works in a browser but the callback function is never called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a new request to the server and you appear to be loading a page that is not loading WordPress core functions. I'd need to see your `HitCount.php` to confirm this but I can't think of another explanation.

Loading WordPRess files piecemeal is tricky and prone to breakage as core code changes. You can probably get it working by loading `wp-load.php`, `wp-settings.php`, or `wp-blog-header.php`. I believe the latter is the officially correct one but it will load theme functions you probably don't need. I don't know for sure about that because I haven't used any of those tricks since the AJAX API became available, which brings me to...

The safest thing to do is use the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), and that is what I recommend unless you really know WordPRess core files and load sequence very very well, and also need extremely quick response. The AJAX API loads a lot so it can be slow, though in personal experience I have never noticed a lag worth worrying about.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the AJAX API but I'm going in circles.. I've updated the main question with the new code but now nothing happens.. at all?

Comment: Going to accept this as the answer and repost a question with my broken AJAX API plugin.. thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Two issues I see in your updated code-

The action you you pass in your js is `LogHit`, but the action you set in `add_action` is `LogHit_callback`: `wp_ajax_nopriv_LogHit_callback`. one of those has to change to match the other.

The `HitCount` function- where is that hooked to add that code to your page? Also within that code block: `jQuery.post(ajaxurl...`, on the front end `ajaxurl` won't be defined. If that gets directly injected into a page then you should set that via `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`. The preferred method is to put that in its own js file, [enqueue it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), then use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to set `ajaxurl`:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-ajax-request',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/your_script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);

wp_localize_script(
    'my-ajax-request',
    'MyAjax',
    array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
);
```

Then use `MyAjax.ajaxurl` in your js:

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here, I had updated the hook calls already and I'm now hardcoding the ajaxurl to take out some of the complexity.. I've updated above to try make this as simple as possible

Comment: @Milo I did your way but I get “You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page” when I use the search form as non-logged-in user. If i search while I am the admin, it works correctly. Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: Fixed it, I had a require_once file that had this code inside it: `if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) ); }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the whole wordPress stuff and in the old days you had to do an `include "../../../wp-load.php"` or something like that.

But, now, best practice is to use `admin-ajax.php` to handle all ajax requests. And you need to understand hooks to do it which I believe you do :)

I would suggest reading this article http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#js-global for starters.