# Can I access Wordpress API's from within plugin scripts?

Tags: plugin-development, customization

I'm developing a WP plugin. In my plugin I have a file that processes form data. For example, user will enter shortcode:

```
[poll-form]
```

And it will output a form with the `action` attribute set to the `/wp-content/plugins/MyPlugin/process_form.php`. I have added a rewrite rule so the new path looks like `/poll-form`.

In `process_form.php` I need to access my plugin settings using the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

I was under the impression that the scripts within my plugin directory have access to the Wordpress Core.

How do I get access to the Wordpress API's from within my script in the plugin?

Comment: I am pretty sure this question is the functional equivalent of this one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80050/21376

Comment: You should never use a plugin file as an AJAX or form endpoint, it's a massive security risk

Comment: @TomJNowell What's the alternative? And what security risks are you talking about that can't be solved with correct validation/sanitization?

Comment: That file will still run even if the plugin is disabled or deactivated. If you need to submit a form on a page, just use that page as the target, and detect at the very top. E.g. If you ask me a question, do I really need to find a 3rd person to give my answer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using ajax refering the process_form.php. However the right way to access any ajax is through the **wp-admin/admin-ajax.php**.

Pull all your code from **process_form.php** to a function (can be added on your main plugin file):

```
function my_process_form() {
    //...code from process_form.php
    if ( ! $error ) { //your error boolean
        return wp_json_success(); //recommend for return an success as JSON
    } else {
        return wp_json_error(); //recommend for return an error as JSON
    }
}
```

Than, add a hook to the ajax action, like so:

```
//You can choose one of those or leave both:
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_process_form', 'my_process_form' ); //Only logged users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_process_form', 'my_process_form' ); //Not logged users
```

In Javascript, you must call the url **wp-admin/admin-ajax.php** with the parameter you hooked, in this case **my_proccess_form**:

PHP calling JS and send the **admin-ajax.php** URL:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_custom.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

wp_localize_script(
    'my-custom-script', //JS referenced above
    'ajax_object', //Javascript Object
    array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) //Same as wp-admin/admin.ajax.php
    )
);
```

I'll send you an example using jQuery for the AJAX request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type : "post",
     dataType : "json", //Example only
     url : ajax_object.ajax_url, //From wp_localize_script
     data : { //can use jQuery.serialize() as well
         action: "my_process_form", //used on wp_ajax_(action) and wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)
         post_id : 1, //Dummy id, more parameters, use comma
         nonce: nonce //Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce
     },
     success: function( response ) {
         if( response.success ) {
             //Success JS Process
         } else {
             alert("Error");
             console.log( response );
         }
     }
});
```

> Referencies
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

---- UPDATE ----

> If you prefer use $_POST without AJAX, you can use the hook
>   [admin_post_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_%28action%29)
>
> HTML example:
>
> ```
> <form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
>   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_process_form">
>   <input type="text" name="name">
>   <input type="email" name="email">
>   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
> ```
>
> PHP Example:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'admin_post_my_process_form', 'my_process_form' );
>
> function my_process_form() {
>     // The process_form.php code here
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm not using Ajax, and it's not an option. 3.2% of my website visitors are using screen readers (mainly Jaws).

Comment: Hi @JamesJeffery, if you want to use only post, you can follow the same idea, but refering the [admin_post(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_%28action%29). Let me know if you need an example.